# Word collage of github repos

Tags: github, tag-cloud

Hi all do you know what that word collage is called? You know like people run on a chat and it shows the most commonly used words? The bigger the word the more common it was.

I had a task to figure out my skillset of working with various components so i thought to make a collage of my code from all my repositories on github.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like a "tag cloud"?

You mean this? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud

I hope this helps

Comment: Ah yes!! Thank you tag cloud!! This helps so much! I was wondering if theres an automatic way to run a tag cloud on all my code, do you know of one?

Comment: Someone already answered that I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580508/how-to-create-a-simple-tag-cloud-using-c-sharp-and-styling-with-css